# How to pass a bitmap from jni/c++ part to java

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, android-source

I am developing an android app and currently, I am getting a lot of frames from my capture card in my c++ library as bitmaps(unsigned long long). Now I need to send the bitmap to the java part so I can display it.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You could, for example, [stuff your frame data](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/bitmap) into a Java `Bitmap`. At what frame rate are you expecting to do this?

Comment: Alternatively, upload your bitmap directly to a GPU texture and render it with OpenGL from either C++ or Java.

Comment: 60 fps. How do I stuff the frame data to the java bitmap?

Comment: Create a `Bitmap` object on the Java side. Pass it to C++ via JNI. Call `AndroidBitmap_lockPixels`, `memcpy` your capture card data into it, call `AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels`.